# Steam tradeoffer error in node.js

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steambot, steamworks-api

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\govind\node-steam-tradeoffers-master\examples\offerbot.js:71
          throw err;
          ^

Error: There was an error sending your trade offer.  Please try again later. (15)
    at SteamTradeOffers.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\govind\node-steam-tradeoffers-master\index.js:315:17)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\User\Desktop\govind\node-steam-tradeoffers-master\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\govind\node-steam-tradeoffers-master\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\govind\node-steam-tradeoffers-master\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-tradeoffers) node.js script to trade skins , i am getting the above stated error(15). This error is because of this [reasons](https://steamerrors.com/15)

```
You may receive this result when sending, accepting, declining, or canceling a trade offer. Below is an explanation of what this result means in this context.

You can't send or accept this trade offer because either you can't trade with the other user, or one of the parties in this trade can't send/receive one of the items in the trade. Possible causes: a) You aren't friends with the other user and you didn't provide a trade token. b) The trade token was wrong. c) You are trying to send or receive an item for a game in which you or the other user can't trade (e.g. due to a VAC ban). d) You are trying to send an item and the other user's inventory is full for that game.
```

The reasons which are stated there are all full-field at my end. There is nothing to do with those reasons from my account.
How I know that :
Just before trading programmatically , I trade manually from official steam website and the result was positive.

But when i did that with same steamid using this bot, it show 15 error code.

if those are the reasons then how could i was able to trade through steam official website??

Anything on this??
would be very appreciable >>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://steamerrors.com/15

a) You aren't friends with the other user and you didn't provide a trade token.

b) The trade token was wrong.

c) You are trying to send or receive an item for a game in which you or the other user can't trade (e.g. due to a VAC ban).

d) You are trying to send an item and the other user's inventory is full for that game.